# Avoid Areas not working in Here Fleet Telematics

Tags: here-api

Im using the "avoidareas" parameter to remove some points from the initial trip. This method worked a couple of months ago, but now it returns the same route as the initial trip, ignoring the "avoidareas" parameter.

Here is the exemple im working with:

"https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={YOUR API KEY}&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled;&currency=EUR&restTimes=EU&traverseGates=true&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&length=13.6&width=2.4m&height=3m&limitedWeight=24000kg&legAttributes=li,-mn,sh&linkAttributes=wn,le,sh,-fc&mapMatchRadius=5000&ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction=5000;0;all&departure=2022-09-08T16:00:00&waypoint0=40.613223,-3.2451044&waypoint1=39.919898,-8.634333&avoidareas41.6419,-5.16831;41.541900000000005,-5.06831"

Am i doing something wrong? Has something been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'avoidAreas' feature works, but the request needs to be verified for the following:

the parameter name is in camelCase, so it should be 'avoidAreas', you are missing "=" sign right after avoidareas in your request url,
avoid area rectangle should be specified by latMax,lonMin;latMin,lonMax

A sample request looks like https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=50.112698,8.675777&waypoint1=48.544180,9.662530&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&departure=2022-08-09T13:12:35&alternatives=0&weightPerAxle=3.25t&limitedWeight=7.5t&height=3.4m&width=2.5m&length=7.2m&trailersCount=1&avoidAreas=48.988757459020015,8.436328214242295;48.94714399157084,8.493687099461848

Thanks

/MS

Comment: I already had the "=" sign in the code, it was just a copy mistake, sorry about that. I had the code running correctly a couple of mounths ago and now coming back to it, it just doesnt work. About the 2 coordinates to define the rectangle to avoid, the documentation states" by specifying a rectangle that contains it (top left 52.517100760,13.3905424488 and bottom right 52.5169701849,13.391808451)"(https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/example-route-avoiding-an-area.html) as i do above (it used to work but now it just doesnt). What's the correct method to do it?